# How to prevent mysqli's constructor from triggering a warning

Tags: php, mysqli, error-handling

I am attempting to extend the mysqli class in PHP. I would like to be able to handle all errors as exceptions so I can choose to recover from them if possible/necessary.

The issue I have is that the mysqli constructor insists on triggering a PHP warning if connection is not made (e.g. because incorrect password), in addition to having variables indicating that the attempt failed.

```
public function __construct()
{
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);
    parent::__construct(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    if ($this->connect_errno > 0)
    {
        throw new ConnectionError($this);
    }
}
```

The warning is triggered where I call the parent constructor. Now it was my understanding that the first line of this function should disable the reports coming from the mysqli object, but either it doesn't work on the constructor or I am not using it correctly.

I also know I could prefix that function call with the error suppression '@' operator, but it is considered bad form to use that operator.

I'm also aware that I could define an overall error handling function which could be used to suppress warnings, but I want to be very specific in suppressing warnings coming only from that one line of code.

Therefore I was wondering if anyone knows how one might stop that warning from being produced in a manner that would be considered good practice or is the only way to use the '@' operator?